# Why do I see two icons for the same application?

Tags: finder, dock, icon

I have installed TinyGrab on my Mac, and set it to run on login. I now see two icons on the dock; when I close one, the other one closes too.

> [image: screenshot]

I have two user accounts on the Mac; while I see some processes that run under the other account, this is not true for TinyGrab. The processes that run under the other account are the following.

> [image: screenshot]

I noticed that the application has its settings for being executed at login, not just the option shown from the Finder, but unchecking one option unchecks also the other one.

Why do I see two icons? How can I avoid it happens?

I have checked, and there is just a copy of the application.

> [image: screenshot]

When I close the application, and I manually reopen it, there is just an icon on the dock; when I restart the Mac, there are two icons.

If I try closing one of the application from the icon from the dock, one closes while the other freezes, while I have to force it to quit, even though it doesn't quit when forcing to quit it either.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple versions installed on your system?

Comment: I am sure. See the update to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things this could be.

- You may be running two different instances of TinyGrab. Spotlight ignores quite a few locations on your Mac. To see where they live, right click each one and choose "Show in Finder" (it may be under options depending on your Mac OS version). If there is a second application, that is your problem.
- You are in fact running two instances of TinyGrab. The default is to only run one instance of any GUI application, but there are options to disable that. To see if this is the case, when both are running open Activity Monitor and search for the program. If you see two entries there, that is the issue. If this is the case you can check the preferences to see if there is a multiple instance option (I didn't find one).

Finally you can also try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/co.uk.keyoneproductions.TinyGrab.plist` and see if that solves the problem. And if that doesn't, try removing your Dock preferences at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist`. If that doesn't work either, try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` and then log out and back in.

Comment: This is funny: Without doing anything, TinyGrab is fine, but now the problem is with DTerm, which is the last application I set to run at login.

Comment: Maybe try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`?

Comment: It seems there is a bug in OS X. I found something in the [Apple Mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2013/Feb/msg00598.html), but there isn't any suggested workaround. The mailing list is for developers, then; if there would be any workaround, that would not be for final users. I am accepting this answer since it is suggesting some steps that are generally valid in such cases. If you would include also the suggestion you gave in your last comment, that would be super.

Answer (score 0):

Find the application in Finder (so that you can put it back in Dock). Then Option-drag the duplicate application of the Dock. If both disappear drag it back from Finder to the Dock.

Comment: I am using OS X 10.8. If I drag the icon off the dock, nothing happens, even using a different modifier or no modifier at all.

Comment: Mmm... must be bug in Mavericks?  Try with another application to see if you can get it on and off the dock.   Otherwise only option I can thing of is removing and replacing application totally